# Send sms from bugzilla

Tags: sms, bugzilla, sms-gateway

I wanted to send sms from bugzilla.
The user tab should have extra firleds to receive users phone number.
If the number is given , a SMS should be sent to the person whom the bug is assigned.
So a sms should be sent along with the email notification.
Is this possible from bugzilla using some extension or plugin ?

Thanks
      Vineeth

Comment: yes it is possible if you have sms gateway,,, bugzilla produces xml format output also for user so setting up SMS is possible

Comment: I know its possible bu then i was hoping there would exist some plugin or addon to bugzilla to do the same.Also the users phone number also needs to be accepted in the user add menu

Comment: i cant find a way to add phone number to users info. do anyone have a lead on that.

Answer (score 0):

To add additional information to a user record, you'll need to add either a column to table `profiles` or add a new table altogether that's keyed on `profiles.userid`. Look at the `Example' extension for some ideas about exactly what to do.

One possible alternative is to create a new pseudo-user for an SMS address that "watches" the real user. That has the added benefit of separating the notifications a user gets by email from those by SMS.

You'll probably also need to add some new templates to format the messages properly.

Answer (score 0):

With a Bugzilla Android Client it is possible....if you use Android phones. In this case a notification is received if the bug is assigned to you and the app is running.